# updaing sql table using UPDATE mysql and php syntax

Tags: php, mysql, html

i am trying to update my records using `UPDATE` in php and mysql , the query working but there is not updates at all happened on the database , i have many records for tickets which i need to update there status when the user purchase them , let say the user books `10` tickets i used this syntax

```
     for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $tickets; $counter++) {
                echo $eventId;
                echo $chooseClass;
                echo $chooseUser;
                $bookTicket = mysql_query("UPDATE units 
SET ticketSold = 'Yes', 
userIdFK = '$chooseUser' 
WHERE BusinessreservationIdFk = '$eventId' 
AND classIDfk ='$choosedClass'"
) or die(mysql_error());

                if ($bookTicket) 
                {
                    echo "<br/>ticket " . $counter . "  done !";
                } 
                else
                {
```

i tried to `echo` all variables here inside the `for loop` to make sure this `for` gets all the variables values , which is working , i have like 1000 tickets already stored on mysql table `units` which i need to update their status from sold = `No` to `Yes`. where is the problem here ?

Comment: Your code may be vulnerable to SQL injection.  You **really** should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to go about it, read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @eggyal thanks , but this is just a model to test :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try building the query separately (e.g. `$sql = 'UPDATE ...'`, so you can do an `echo $sql` and copy/paste the query and run it manually. Nothing in your code looks wrong, so the values you're passing around must not be correct or the `WHERE ...` logic isn't proper. So run a sample query manually and see if anything happens then.

However, note that you're doing this inside a `for()` loop, but aren't using that $counter value anywhere. In effect you're just running the SAME query over and over. Setting `ticketSold` to `Yes` $counter times isn't going to make it "more" `Yes` than if you'd done this update only once.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for replying ,how do i run the sql statement manually ?

Comment: Using the mysql monitor (aka command prompt), or something like the web-based phpmyadmin.

Comment: @MarcB , i tried this one on mysql query inside navicat mysql software , `UPDATE units SET ticketSold = 'No', userIdFK = '121' WHERE BusinessreservationIdFk = '108' AND classIDfk ='135';` and it worked !

Comment: OK , i found that one of the variables are wrong ! , rookie mistake, thanks for your help